# Troubleshooting Apache ProxyPass Error 500 for WebSockets in VHost Config

Tags: apache-2.4, websocket

I'm encountering an issue with my Apache VHost configuration, and I could use some help to understand and resolve it. Here are the details:

I have a Linux server with the following specifications:

```
Hostname: 3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 7 15:41:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Apache Version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Apache Build Date: Apr 5, 2023 17:18:30


I've also installed V2Ray listening on port 8080
```

In my VHost configuration file (vhost.conf), I have the following setup for SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName hostname
    DocumentRoot /home/wwww
    <Location "/server">
        ProxyPass wss://127.0.0.1:8080/server
        ProxyPassReverse wss://127.0.0.1:8080/server
    </Location>
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My issue is with the `<Location>` block where I'm trying to set up a WebSocket proxy. When using `wss://`, I encounter Error 500 (Internal Server Error). Strangely, I don't face any issues with port 80 on the same VHost configuration. I've checked the `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, but there is no meaningful information regarding the error.

I'm looking for guidance on what might be causing this Error 500 with WebSocket `(wss://)` and how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!